# Spaces in a text area

Tags: php, textarea, spaces

I have a textarea where the user can input text.  If the user types and goes to a new line, and continues writing text, or starts a new paragraph, when the content of the textarea is sent by a form using $_POST, and printed again, the content has no spaces or new lines showing in it.  It displays as one chunk of text.  Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1):

HTML [displays multiple spaces and line breaks as one space](http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html). This means you will need to do your own formatting to make it display as in the `<textarea>`. You can use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert new lines into `<br>` and replace spaces with `nbsp;` using [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or similar functions. You could also wrap the text in `<pre>` tags as well.